# While loop is not terminating due to socket function

Tags: python, loops, sockets, while-loop

I am trying to run two while loops in this program. **The first while loop needs to run up to 50 seconds but this loop does not exit after 50 seconds (Not terminating after 50 Seconds)**, it just continues. I verified the timer in a separate program, where timer works well,but in my program timer is not working.

```
import array
import time 
import socket  
import os,sys
import concurrent.futures
import struct 

Nmax_Per_hop=100
hello_Broadcast_Period=40
NeighborDiscovery_Time_Interval=50
MyNeighborSet_ip=[]
all_ip=[]
a=10
b=0
start_time=time.time()
My_ip='192.168.1.1'
#############################################################################
def broadcast_hello():           # (send 'Hello message')
    ip1 = "192.168.1.254"
    print ("[tx]------>hello to:"+ ip1)
    PORT = 12345

    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as s:
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_BROADCAST,1)
        s.sendto (b'Hello',('192.168.1.254',PORT))
##########################################################################

def received_hello():      
    PORT = 12345
    ip=[]
    recv_message_hello=[]
    global a
    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind(('',PORT))
    message=s.recvfrom(4096)
    print ("before the ip") 
    ip=message[1][0]
    if (ip not in all_ip):
        all_ip.append(ip)
        print (all_ip)
        
    recv_message=message[0]  
    if not recv_message in recv_message_hello:
        recv_message_hello=recv_message

    if (ip==My_ip):
        pass
    elif ip not in MyNeighborSet_ip :
        MyNeighborSet_ip.append(ip)
    else:
        print ("Already in List")

    print ("[N-Set]------------:",MyNeighborSet_ip)

##########################################################################

temp = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor (max_workers=2)
```

## Here this loop is not working well

```
while(((time.time()-start_time)<NeighborDiscovery_Time_Interval) and (len(MyNeighborSet_ip) <= Nmax_Per_hop)):

    if (time.time()-start_time<hello_Broadcast_Period):
        temp.submit(broadcast_hello)
    try:
        temp.submit(received_hello)
    except:
        print("###################")

print ("IP of this node is: ",My_ip)
print ("[N-Set]------------:",MyNeighborSet_ip)

while (b<10):
    print ("dfdfdfdfdfdfdfdf")
    b+=1
```

Can anybody help me how to fix this problem?

Comment: Hello ! Could you please reduce your code to a simple snippet showing what's not working ? It would be easier for the community to help you if you do so. Also, you're referring to another program, could you please embed it in the question ?

Comment: @Lescurel, In my Program, it has only two functions, which is used inside the while loop. My problem is that, First while loop is not terminating, it has timer of 50seconds but it is not terminating.
Because of First while loop problem, second while loop is not executing. 
If you again cloud not understand, then i can give more detail. 
Thanks for kind cooperation.

Comment: @usman1644 Lescruel asked you to modify your question, i.e. to edit it down to a smaller snippet that isolates the part that is not working.  Please do that.  The easier you make it for others to help you, the more help you will get.

Comment: @ huck_cussler  inside code i mentioned where is my problem. I tried to reduced the code, but in actual, i am using two functions inside the while loop, that is why i can not exclude these two functions from program. If i will exclude, then no body can fix my problem because the problem is anywhere in these two functions.

Comment: Your loop runs for 50 seconds, and it spends most of that time submitting thousands of requests for `broadcast_hello` to be executed later by a worker thread.  On my machine it takes about four times as long for those requests to be handled as it does to submit them. That's why you think the timer doesn't work -- it takes ~200 seconds for the queued requests to be handled.  You would be better off just calling `broadcast_hello` directly from the loop instead of requesting asynchronous execution.

Comment: @ ottomeister Yes you are right. 
But if I want to run parallelly both broadcasting and receiving, and also if I want to implement according to the timer(50seconds), then how I can stop the receiving after 50 seconds. 
I mean how I can kill the remaining process after 50seconds?